# Sonar-runner: Command not found

Tags: xcode, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

```
-n Running Tailor...
-n Running Lizard..
++ sonar-runner
./run-sonar-swift.sh: line 82: sonar-runner: command not found
++ returnValue=127
++ set +x
ERROR - Command 'sonar-runner ' failed with error code: 127
```

I'm getting this message while Generating sonar report on Mac using Jenkins, about 2 weeks ago it was working fine but now I'm getting the error message.

Things which I did Last week :
Updated my mac mini OS to Latest
Updated XCode 10.3 to 11.1 but then just because of that error again downgraded to 10.3
Still getting that error message.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved it, sonar-runner is deprecated now instead we have to use sonar-scanner but my project was built on sonar-runner if I want to make it as sonar-runner then I have to edit all the files which I can't, so instead of updating all the files I downloaded the old sonar-runner binaries and placed it in the same directory as sonar-scanner;also added the PATH to bash_profile.

Then I triggered the job then it worked...!!!